# Qiskit gates out of order?

Tags: qiskit

I'm running the following piece of code and get the following output.

```
n = 4
qc = QuantumCircuit(n)
for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
    qc.h(i)
    print("h", i)
    for j in range(i - 1, -1, -1):
        qc.cp(math.pi / 2 ** (i - j), j, i)
        print("cp", j, i)
qc.draw()
```

[image]
I'm wondering why the second H gate appears before the third CP gate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output circuit perfectly matches with the code.The  second hadamard gate is not affecting the 3rd CP, so the order does not matter. Qiskit does this to make the output circuit image compact. A barrier can be put to match the sequence you expect from Qiskit.The same visual alteration is seen when applying measurements.[image: Circuit with barrier]